# Do I need to configure Load Ba-lancer for configuring 5 node Kafka cluster on Linux RHEL7.5 virtual Machine

Tags: apache-kafka, load-balancing, rhel7

Am configuring 5 node Kafka cluster on Linux RHEL7.5 virtual Machine, Do i need to configure Load Ba-lancer? If yes on which node i need to configure and on which port?

Comment: Please read the Kafka documentation. Kafka consumers and producers   ensures load balancing depending on topics and partitions and replication factor

Comment: Thank you asolanki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not need to add a load balancer on top of kafka. The concept of consumer groups in Kafka will take care of balancing the load.

For example, if you expect topic A to have high rate of incoming events per minute, you can create topic A with say 5 paritions. You can then fire up 5 instances of the consumer with the same consumer group id and each partition gets assigned to each of them. You can add paritions and consumer instances as per the expected traffic requirements.

Refer to https://kafka.apache.org/documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank u vallikranth.